# Parameter checking in C preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

How can I test which identifier is passed as the value of a macro parameter in **C** at compile time?

I'm writing wrapper macros for a micro-controller in **C** (GNU).

I have some macros that work like this:

```
#define _ReadBits(port, mask)      (PORT ## port) & (mask)
#define ReadBits(portmask)         _ReadBits(portmask) 
#define SWITCH D, (1<<7)
```

This way I can say:

```
foo = ReadBits(SWITCH);
```

and I'll get

```
foo = PORTD & (1<<7);
```

That works great. I want to expand these to do something like this:

```
#define _ConfigAnalog(port, mask)  BUILD_BUG_ON(port != B); AD1PCFGCLR = (mask)
#define ConfigAnalog(portmask)    _ConfigAnalog(portmask)
```

That is, I want a compile-time error to happen if parameter `port` isn't `B` (because this micro-controller can configure *only* port `B` as analog).

Is there some way to do this in **C**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out myself:

```
#define PORT_B_SUPPORTS_ANALOG

#define __CheckPort(p)  PORT_##p##_SUPPORTS_ANALOG
#define __ConfigAnalogBits(mask) AD1PCFGCLR = (mask)

#define _ConfigAnalogBits(port, mask)  __CheckPort(port); __ConfigAnalogBits(mask)
#define ConfigAnalogBits(portmask)     _ConfigAnalogBits(portmask)

#define NO_GOOD C, (1<<3)
#define VOLTAGE B, (1<<3)

void tryit(void)
{
    ConfigAnalogBits(VOLTAGE);
    //ConfigAnalogBits(NO_GOOD);
}
```

If "port" is B then _CheckPort compiles into a null statement.

If "port" is anything else, a build error happens.

Comment: Avoid using identifiers that start with an underscore followed by either another underscore or an uppercase letter (e.g. avoid `__this` and `_This`) because such identifiers are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @dreamlax: Thanks; will fix.

Comment: This does **not** test any "string value" of a macro  parameter. It tests an identifier name. Should the downvote in my answer be yours, I'd think it fair to reconsider if your question (which I cite) is maybe not stated as clearly as it could.

Comment: @Jens: Whether the first line uses "string" instead of "identifier" - which is an understandable colloquialism/mistake in my opinion - the rest of the question made it perfectly clear what he meant.

Comment: @Jens I edited the question to remove the confusing reference to "string value"

Answer (score 0):

> How can I test the string value of a macro parameter in C at compile?

You can't.

According to C99 6.10.1 *Conditional inclusion*, pre-processor conditions must be an *integer constant expressions*, and may test whether a macro is defined (using `#if`, `#ifdef identifier` or `#if defined(identifier)`).

Comment: I think the C preprocessor is Turing complete. So you always can; the question is just how.

Comment: @nerdfever.com Turing completeness has nothing to do with arbitrary input data manipulation. A language can be Turing complete over moonbeams. That doesn't mean it can make decisions about strings.

Comment: @Gene: If you can encode strings in moonbeams, then I think you can made decisions about strings. (In principle anyway; not saying it's practical.)